# Ficha limpa dos candidatos

Tags: debate, eleição

Não existe um critério para os candidatos que se candidataram para ser moderadores? Tipo ficha limpa?

Falo isso porque já vi candidatos que tiveram contas bloqueadas, advertências por terem cometidos alguma infração dentro da comunidade.

Ai vem minha dúvida, se esses candidatos tentaram fazer isso quando eram usuários normais com alguns privilégios o que farão quando forem moderadores?  Quem os advertirão quando ou se voltarem a cometer esses erros novamente?

Comment: Entendo que é algo a se pensar, mas se o usuário foi advertido, suspenso, e está na ativa, em teoria cumpriu a "pena" né? Lembrando ainda que moderadores não estão "absolutamente acima da lei", só tem umas ferramentas a mais. AGORA, isso não quer dizer que não seja motivo pra lascar um -1 na pessoa se entender justo, afinal o voto é livre ;)

Comment: Eu sei como responder isso, mas me absterei para não parecer campanha eleitoral. Seria só o que o Bacco comentou com um ponto adicional.

Comment: Marconcílio Souza como é que consegues ver contas bloqueadas e advertências por terem cometidos alguma infração dentro da comunidade?

Comment: @bigown acho que devias responder, mesmo que possa parecer campanha.

Comment: @JorgeB. aí eu posso ser advertido e virar ficha suja :P

Comment: @bigown acho que devias só por esse comentário! :D

Comment: @JorgeB. Safadinho :D Posso até fazer depois, assim fica uma informação para próxima, com o processo em andamento e eu sendo parte interesseda seria imprudente.

Comment: Se o processo não tivesse sido iniciado, seria uma discussão pertinente e boa de se resolver o quanto antes, mas como a questão foi levantada na "metade" do jogo, eu até acho legal discutir o assunto depois mesmo. Inclusive porque, a resposta está na própria pergunta, é "não, não há um critério de ficha limpa"

Comment: @JorgeB. quando um usuário fica suspenso do uso da comunidade aparece na página de perfil dele, e falando um pouco de que ele cometeu.

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza então você se lembra de ter visto candidatos suspensos é isso?

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, mas não vou mencionar quem é nem que seja a força kkkk

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza na verdade o que fala é muito genérico e beira a leviandade tentar inferir o que é de fato. O que eu sei é que eu nunca fui suspenso, isso eu posso falar :P

Comment: Quer disse então que se uma pessoa foi passível de pena um vez, ela não se enquadra mais na comunidade e devemos olhar para ela com desdem e restringir suas ações? humm, interessante.

Comment: @bigown, cada um tem sua consciência do que faz. nunca vi você suspenso ou que tenha cometido infração. mas não vou expor quem tenha cometido isso aqui pelo fato de puder ser prejudicado no futuro. (Tipo sai votando negativo nas minhas perguntas ou respostas) , mas acredito que os moderadores atuais devem ter um históricos desses usuários.

Comment: Concordo com o @GuilhermeLautert. Se o membro já foi punido, mas seu comportamento atual no site está dentro da "normalidade" esperada, ele é tão candidato quanto a outros que não tenham sofrido punição.

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza pode ser até alguns  da comunidade saibam, e tem uns casos desses que eu suspeito que até refletiram nos votos, mas realmente concordo que não venha muito ao caso apontar o dedo. A discussão é interessante, só o _timing_ dela que ficou meio estranho.

Comment: Acho que não entenderam bem a pergunta ... (Quem os advertirão quando ou se voltarem a cometer esses erros novamente?)

Comment: MarconcílioSouza os moderadores podem ser punidos como membros comuns também. Caso os mesmos se comportem de forma abusiva que prejudique a comunidade, podem ser "exonerados" da função, ou até banidos, dependendo da gravidade do ato. O CM pode remover moderadores, no SOPT, temos o @Gabe.

Comment: Como comentei, eles sao usuários normais, só tem algumas ferramentas a mais. E como o @diegofm disse, temos os CM acima deles.

Comment: @Bacco, entendi.

Comment: Conheço pelo menos um caso de um usuário que foi suspenso em um site da rede SE e depois se tornou moderador em um outro site da rede SE, enquanto ainda está suspenso no primeiro site. Entretanto, não quero mencioná-lo explicitamente para evitar de colocar lenha na fogueira.

Comment: Concordo completamente com o [primeiro comentário do @Bacco](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5196/ficha-limpa-dos-candidatos#comment18859_5196). Aliás, a moderação é só mais uma forma de participação no site. E o mecanismo de punição **já existe**: um usuário com direitos suprimidos pelo período de carência estipulado nas regras, já não pode se candidatar. Tirar um direito após o cumprimento desse período (seja ele o direito de se candidatar, de votar, de editar, ou qualquer outro) parece injusto e, efetivamente, desnecessário.

Comment: @LuizVieira, Fiz essa pergunta pelo fato de ser os moderadores que advertem sobre infrações cometidas no site. Mas já foi esclarecido isso.

Comment: @LuizVieira, No mundo real você faria o mesmo? após um criminoso cometer um crime você o trataria-o como se fosse normal ou teria um pezinho atras? Garanto que você não contrataria uma babá para cuida de um filho se soubesse que ela já foi presa por maltratar uma criança:), Mas em fim isso é no mundo real.

Comment: No mundo real eu procuraria conhecer a pessoa, considerando não somente o fato de ela ter cumprido pena mas as razões para a condenação e os atos dela antes e depois da pena (o que eu acho que é justamente **o ponto-chave** da resposta do @utluiz). Os indivíduos são diferentes, de forma que a gama de razões que pode ter levado alguém ao crime é bem grande. Uma linha de raciocínio que trata todo mundo da mesma forma (não leve a mal, não é uma crítica, é só um contra-argumento) não traz nenhum bem aos indivíduos envolvidos, e consequentemente, nenhum bem à comunidade.

Comment: E eu não tinha entendido que já tinha sido esclarecido. Não quis prolongar a discussão, desculpe. :)

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza Não só o site não é o mundo real, ser suspenso não significa que você cometeu um crime, e uma eleição tem menos margem para suspresas que uma contratação individual `:)`

Answer (score 18):

Muito interessante esta pergunta. Vou deixar o meu ponto de vista.

## Ficha suja

O que seria isso é algo complicado de se definir. Poderíamos ficar semanas debatendo quais regras e quantas infrações, ou qualquer combinação disso, efetivamente iria sujar o histórico de um candidato.

O modo mais simplista, isto é, considerar qualquer infração, seria injusto. Muitos usuários podem ter sido advertidos por motivos menores e os moderadores não tinham em mente qualquer impacto no futuro daquele usuário.

Aliás, seria mais um fardo para os moderadores levarem. Agora, na hora de decidir se alguém vai ser ou não advertido, teremos que levar a carga de estar condenando o usuário para sempre.

## A escolha é sua e de toda a comunidade

Eu acho que a ideia de verificar o histórico dos usuários é excelente. Mas não acho que devemos nos ater a um ponto específico.

Olhe tudo o que o seu candidato fez:

- Suas perguntas ou ausência delas.
- Suas respostas ou ausência delas.
- Repare no tom. Ele respeita os demais? Será que você quer alguém que perde a cabeça fácil e discute com os outros tendo o poder de moderador?
- Repare em como ele interage com os demais. Ele agrega para o site? Ou sempre que ele mete o bedelho as coisas descambam?
- Considere a participação no site. Ele tem uma participação equilibrada e contínua?
- Note a participação dele no Meta. Ele defende o que você deseja para o site no futuro? Os moderadores não determinam como as coisas acontecem, mas tem grande influência, principalmente nos novos usuários. Por exemplo, alguns usuários querem que a comunidade seja mais aberta ou menos restritiva (priorizam ajudar), outros mais fechada ou mais restritiva (priorizam qualidade) e nem sempre é fácil chegar a um equilíbrio. Se você votar em alguém que almeja algo diferente do que você, talvez esteja condenando sua própria experiência no site.
- Capacidade de julgamento. Veja se o candidato tomou uma posição sensata, na sua opinião, quando houve alguma polêmica. Você não vai querer alguém "extremista" ou que muda de ideia toda hora de acordo com a influência dos demais.

Resumindo, assuma a responsabilidade sobre a sua decisão e não vote apenas pela imagem ou pela reputação ou mesmo pelo quanto o usuário é antigo no site.

Pense que amanhã ele vai estar "julgando" suas ações no site. Independente das punições que ele já teve, considere se a *atitude* geral do indivíduo é algo que você respeita e quer reproduzir nos demais usuários.

#### Atualização

Obviamente, não é esperado que todos os moderadores pensem de forma igual e a comunidade não aceitaria um moderador desequilibrado e autoritário.

Entretanto, tive dois objetivos em mente com os critérios acima:

- Que os candidatos obviamente inaptos sejam prontamente desconsiderados. Os quatro primeiros tópicos cobrem isto.
- Há muitos candidatos bons, então é realmente difícil escolher entre os melhores. Portanto, nesse quesito, minha sugestão é comparar o quanto a "filosofia" desse usuário é parecida com a sua. Os três últimos tópicos cobrem isto.

Comment: Não entendi direito esse ponto, tem como elaborar melhor? _"Por exemplo, se você acha que perguntas sobre Arduino deveriam fazer parte do escopo do SOpt e este é um tema primário para você, não faz sentido votar em alguém que discorda veementemente disto, faz?"_ - A impressão que me dá é que isso é uma decisão comunitária, e não prerrogativa de moderação, é? Normalmente os moderadores agiriam na ausência da comunidade, e não no lugar desta, certo? Eu acho que o papel do usuário neste quesito não poderia ser confundido com o do moderador, pois seriam atribuições completamente diferentes.

Comment: @Bacco É *também* papel dos moderadores levantar essas questões se julgarem necessário, guiar e vigiar as discussões para que elas sejam sempre construtivas e tentem chegar à uma solução. Moderadores não são o braço autoritário da comunidade, são líderes dentro dela. Exercerem sua inflência em busca do que acreditam ser melhor para o grupo está muito longe de ser um exercício de individualismo autoritário.

Comment: @Gabe é exatamente o que eu penso. Por isso não faz sentido a frase como critério. Não consigo imaginar um moderador fechando uma questão de Arduino pq pessoalmente não gosta daquilo, portanto a assertiva pra mim não fez sentido. Ao menos, das pessoas com representividade na eleição, acho que realmente estão bem acima desse nível. Creio que está havendo uma inversão de valores muito grande, colocando o que as pessoas pensam como usuário como sendo a baliza que usariam na moderação.

Comment: @Bacco A pergunta não implicava que o mod "fecharia" a pergunta, mas sim que um mod pode discordar da presença de perguntas assim no site e tentar agir para que elas saiam do escopo, por exemplo.

Comment: Sim, percebi isso. Só acho que é nivelar por baixo, pq não vi isso acontecendo com os atuais mods eleitos, e não imagino que aconteceria com qualquer outro. Mas pra não encompridar demais, já esclareceu bem. Só queria confirmar se foi isso mesmo que eu li (e se o @utluiz pensar diferente disso, só deixar um comment tambem, imaginei que fosse coisa dele, e não uma "conclusão coletiva" de vcs).

Comment: @Bacco Eu pequei pelo péssimo exemplo, mas foi praticamente o que o Gabe disse. Moderadores influenciam bastante, se não tanto nos usuários mais antigos, nos mais novos com certeza. Como moderador, ao ver algum conteúdo que não está claramente no escopo, eu posso decidir "aplicar a regra" ou me esforçar para "salvá-lo". Muitas vezes eu peguei questões "perdidas" com 3 ou 4 votos de fechamento, as reescrevi e elas foram depois respondidas.

Comment: @utluiz justamente, não consigo imaginar que qualquer moderador qualificado vá fazer diferente disso (mesmo se fosse uma coisa que antes de ser moderador ele votaria pra fechar). Mas a intenção era realmente de esclarecimento, pois me pareceu meio estranho no meio dos outros ítens. Grato pelo feedback!

Comment: @Bacco Reescrevi o trecho. Se tiver mais algum feedback fique à vontade.

Comment: Além de concordar que a remoção do direito de se candidatar é injusta e efetivamente pouco efetiva, concordo também que seria somente algo a mais pra atrapalhar a vida dos demais moderadores. E concordo também que a escolha dos moderadores é algo que todos devemos fazer com cuidado (tal qual a escolha de qualquer representante, seja no seu condomínio, estado ou país).

Comment: Mas, vale lembrar dois pontos importantes. (1) Esses itens que você elenca são bem subjetivos, *tal qual* a definição do que é ficha suja. "As coisas descambam", por exemplo, pode ser enxergada tanto de forma meramente destrutiva como de forma disruptiva, com a intenção de melhorar algo que não está bom.

Comment: (2) O moderador não tem realmente tanto "poder" assim. É verdade que  o voto dele fecha imediatamente uma questão, mas uma questão fechada pode ser reaberta pelos demais membros. Influência é também relativa. Eu tendo a acreditar que quem se expressa melhor costuma ter muito mais influência nos demais do que quem meramente apresenta um diamante no nome.

Comment: Para a sua resposta ficar perfeita, acho que só falta um ponto: As pessoas mudam ao longo do tempo. Ninguém muda da noite para o dia, mas mudam com o passar dos anos. O usuário X de três anos atrás tende a ter um comportamento diferente do usuário X de hoje. Alguns mudam para melhor, outros mudam para pior. Alguns mudam de ponto de vista e passam a defender coisas com as quais não concordavam antes ou a rejeitar coisas que defendiam no passado. Então, para julgar se alguém seria um bom moderador, é importante ver como ele se comporta no presente e no passado recente, não num passado distante.

Comment: @VictorStafusa bem observado. E vou mais além. Tenho certeza que eu, se fosse moderador, faria muitas coisas de maneira completamente diferente do que faço como usuário. Isso é responsabilidade com a função. E é o que eu espero de qualquer moderador decente. Separar o pessoal do coletivo.